# Multiple document root with nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite, url

I need to configure nginx so it serves a different software from a different document root on a domain's subdirectory as follows:

```
http://example.com/... - main site from /var/www/main
http://example.com/docs/ - an independent application from /var/www/app
```

I tried many ways including proxy_pass and alias but none of them worked for me.
The latest config is the following:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        root /var/www/main;
        index index.html;

        location /docs/ {
           root /var/www/app;
        }
}
```

When I try to access http://example.com/docs/ I see 404 Not Found Error and the following message in the error_log:

*1 "/var/www/app/docs/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory

So it tries to open `/var/www/app/docs/index.html` instead of `/var/www/app/index.html`.

I know this could be fixed by the means of `rewrite` as follows:
`rewrite ^/docs/(.*)$ /$1 last;`. It works for me but it also rewrites all relative links to all assets so it's not the case.

Update:

1) my problem with `alias`:

```
location /docs/ {
   autoindex on;

   alias /var/www/app/;
}
```

"/var/www/app/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory)

2) Problem with proxy_pass:

```
    location /docs/ {
       proxy_pass: http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

...
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;

    root   /var/www/app;
    index  index.html;
}
```

The error is the following:

```
/var/www/app/docs/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Your answer is [right here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) in the official documentation.

Comment: Please see me above. I have already tried alias with no success. /var/www/app/index.html" is not found. Permissions are all set.

Comment: What is the actual file in `/var/www/app` that you want to be shown?